# Is it possible to use OSRM in order to calculate routing into a building?

Tags: gis, osrm

I would to know :
If we save in OSRM server a dataset of points stored from a GPS tracker into a building (a flat one) : is it possible to request the server in order to find the shortest way from a point to another ?
The aim would be to help customers/employees find their way into a place which has not any standard GIS data like roads, street and so on (like a stadium used during a convention, a zoo, an amusement park, and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point clouds are not a valid data format for the OSRM. You will need OSM data. So you could use your GPS points to create a OSM Map of your building. For more infos about indoor mapping see: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Indoor_Mapping

Comment: Oh thanks to you ! That was this kind of answers I was waiting for :)